# How do i say this in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a mage for a game at my science club, and I want to say "if there are no fire or earth mages (represented by "Fire" and "Earth") and nobody to take health from (represented by absorb_target_index ) attack first enemy." how do I say this in python?
thanks for any help!
edit: I'm trying to make an "if" statement. Sorry, I'm quite new to coding so I don't really know what details to include to make a proper question. To attack I use a spell called "Water Jet". absorb_target_index gets its value when the code checks the enemies and if they are below a certain health and I am above a certain health, they are added to the index.

Comment: By using the `print()` function? It's not clear what you mean by "say"

Comment: You return to any tutorial or educational materials on compound expressions in an `if` statement.  You refer to your code for variable names.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 2):

let's say you're doing it like this...

```
Fire = []
Earth = []
absorb_target_index = []
#you have another function which populates these lists with the names of Earth and Fire mages, you would then do
if len(Fire) == 0 and len(Earth) == 0 and len(absorb_target_index) == 0:
    Attack()
```

Like the comments say though, your question is too vague. How does your game define "attacking" an enemy? How are the other mages identified? Where does "absorb_target_index" get its values?

Answer (score 1):

I guess... based on what you've said, you could do...

```
if ((Fire != True) or (Earth != True)) and absorb_target_index != True:
    DoSomething()
```

But without knowing more of what you want, that's about as helpful as I can get?